# Port forward or DMZ not working on tp-link archer a7 ac1750

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, forwarding, dmz

i have minecraft server on a old pc with debian, portforward in the router doesn't work
i also tried DMZ but not works, 2 months ago port forward works, today i changed my lan ip address and subnet mask from 192.168.0.0, 255.255.255.0 to 10.0.0.1, 255.0.0.0 and portforward & dmz not working, i need 10.0 ip range, i also tried mac cloning my lan mac address but not working

ipconfig: https://prnt.sc/s34416

sorry for bad english, i'm from romania.

please, help me

Comment: In your router’s web interface, you should be able to see your WAN IP address. Does it match what "What is my IP" websites report? What’s your ISP?

Comment: my isp is RCS & RDS, port works on internal ip but on external not works

Comment: Please check your WAN IP address as I described. // Did you try using the port forwarding from inside your network or from outside (for example using mobile broadband)? From inside, they may not work.